# get cron scheduler value - Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, cron, cron-task

I want to get a value of Cron Scheduler from my configuration file.

I am not gonna use scheduler to run the process, but I need to pass it to config file so I can change it in the future to the different date instead of changing my code.

```
application.daily.run-scheduler=${APPLICATION_RUN_SCHEDULER:0 0 17 ? * MON-FRI}
```

Is it possible to retrieve a date and/or time from this cron scheduler and use it as a condition in my code?

Thank you for your help. love!

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely.

With a schedule, there's two things you can ask of it.

1. When does it next run
2. Should it run "now".

cron historically (and I imagine similarly here) runs every minute, and looks at the current schedules and asks "Should I run now".

This is actually a pretty easy test.

Finding out when a schedule next runs is far, far more involved. As I recall, it was probably 200 lines of code to figure it all out. Doing this brings in all of the joys and pain of leap years, and days, and daylight savings, etc. Much different from "does it run now".

So, I can't speak to Spring specifically.

All I can say having done it myself is, getting the next time is unlikely.